# Is Mercer real?

Tags: do-androids-dream-of-electric-sheep

I just finished the book. The first as Sci-fi I've ever read. One aspect of the book that confused me was the concept of Mercerism. The Androids and Buster Friendly state that Mercer is a hoax who in reality is a drunk, however later on in the book Mercer appears to Deckard and saves his life, then there's the weird identity crisis Deckard suffers where he believes he Is Mercer himself and gets hit with an actual stone, leading me to believe he is in fact Mercer or he is hallucinating due to over exhaustion and the previous events. I'm a little confused as to if Mercer is in fact a messiah or a fake, did I miss something?

Comment: Your last paragraph is off-topic here - I recommend moving it into a comment.

Comment: https://www.shmoop.com/do-androids-dream-of-electric-sheep/mercerism-symbol.html

Comment: At least you didn't start with Three Sigmata...  ;)

Comment: [Here some Cyberpunk books.](https://www.goodreads.com/list/show/486.Best_cyberpunk_books) also the films Blade Runner and the upcoming Blade Runner 2049 were inspired by the book.

Comment: PKD's answer to your question as to whether Mercer is the messiah or a fake would be 'yes....maybe...'. It's unanswered--and, arguably, unanswerable. It's meant to be ambiguous. The question is really one not of truth but of verisimilitude. In fiction there are truths and meaning that resonate or are believable (verisimilitude). In non-fiction there are facts that are verifiable. Both tell stories and have truths; but, they do so in different ways, by different means. So, I suppose we could say that Mercer is, in some way, PKD's response to critics of, say, ScFi who say its 'just fiction'...

Comment: You can use Google Scholar and search for "Wilbur Mercer" (100+ results); Or, look into critical studies of DADOES/BR or SciFi more broadly (e.g. 'post-humanism'); Or, if you can access online journals, try this: http://online.liverpooluniversitypress.co.uk/doi/abs/10.3828/extr.2013.10?journalCode=extr